# pulling data from txt file getting java.lang.Arrayindexoutofboundsexception errors

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception, usage-statistics, cmdline-args

can someone please help me figure out what the indexes should be to get this to run fully I've tried all kinds of fixes and nothing is working properly. I have a feeling that the issue is in the first declaration of `data`
`String[][] data = new String[MAXPASSENGERS][6];`
First error is here:

```
int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`
>   at Titanic.getTotalNumberofPerishedPassengers(Titanic.java:43)1

Second error is here:

```
int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
```

and here

```
return getTotalPassengers() - getTotalNumberofPerishedPassengers();
```

with these errors

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>   at Titanic.getTotalNumberofPerishedPassengers(Titanic.java:43)

and

```
return getTotalPassengers() - getTotalNumberofPerishedPassengers();
```

Third error:

```
int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1, at TItanic.getTotalNumberofSurvivedPassengerByClass(Titanic.java:71)

How do I fix these to make my code run properly? I've tried changing the array value, but that doesn't do anything and I get the same incorrect results.

```
/**
```

* file: TestTitanic.java Author: Date: 8May15
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 TestTitanic used to test the titanic data
 */
public class TestTitanic {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fileName = "";
    Titanic titanic = null;

    //Get the file name from command line arguments
    if (args.length > 0) {
        fileName = args[0];
    } else {
        fileName = "titaniiiic.txt";
    }

    // Check the file and create titanic statistics
    try {
        titanic = new Titanic(fileName);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    //The application should keep track of the elapsed time (in seconds) 
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //A user-friendly and well-organized menu s
    String choices[] = {"Total number of passengers on the Titanic",
        "Total number of passengers who perished on the Titanic",
        "Total number of Passengers who survived the sinking of the Titanic",
        "Number of passengers who survived the sinking of the Titanic as a function of the passenger class (e.g. 1,2,3)",
        "Number of passengers who survived the sinking of the Titanic as a function of the passenger gender (e.g., male, female)",
        "A list of the names of passengers who paid greater than $200 for their tickets",
        "A list of the names of passengers who were less than 10 years old who survived",
        "A list of the names of passengers who were less than 10 years old who perished ",
        "The count of the number of passengers as a function of the first letter of their last name. (e.g., A: 13, B:33 …)", "Exit"
    };

    int choice = menuChoice(choices);
    while (choice != 10) {
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Total number of passengers on the Titanic: " + titanic.getTotalPassengers());
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Total number of passengers who perished on the Titanic: " + titanic.getTotalNumberofPerishedPassengers());
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Total number of passengers who survived : " + titanic.getTotalNumberofSurvivedPassengers());
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.print("Enter class (e.g. 1,2,3): ");
                int cls = getIntInRange(1, 3);
                System.out.println(cls + " class number of passengers who survived: " + titanic.getTotalNumberofSurvivedPassengersByClass(cls));
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.print("Names of passengers who were less than 10 years old who survived: ");
                System.out.println(titanic.getSurvivedNamesLessGivenAge(10));
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.print("Enter the letter: ");
                char ch = getString().charAt(0);
                System.out.println("Count: " + titanic.getCountByFirstLetterOfFirstName(ch));
                break;
        }
        choice = menuChoice(choices);
    }

    //The application should keep track of the elapsed time (in seconds) 
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
    /**
     * After the program is exited, the application should provide a prompt
     * thanking the user for trying the Titanic program and providing the
     * total time elapsed.
     */
    System.out.println("Thank you for trying the Titanic program");
    System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + elapsedTime);
}

/**
 * Helper method to get String from user
 *
 * @return
 */
public static String getString() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    return input.nextLine();
}

/**
 * Helper method to get user input in range
 *
 * @param low
 * @param high
 * @return
 */
public static int getIntInRange(int low, int high) {
    int num = 0;
    do {
        num = getInt();
        if (num < low || num > high) {
            System.out.println("Enter number between " + low + " and " + high);
        }
    } while (num < low || num > high);
    return num;
}

/**
 *
 * method to display organized menu to user
 *
 * @param choices
 * @return
 */
public static int menuChoice(String choices[]) {
    int choice = 0;
    System.out.println("");
    for (int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + choices[i]);
    }
    System.out.print("Enter choice (1-" + choices.length + "): ");
    choice = getIntInRange(1, choices.length);
    return choice;
}

/**
 * Helper method to get int from user
 *
 * @return
 */
    public static int getInt() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = -1;
        boolean good;
            do {
            good = true;
            try {
                num = input.nextInt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            good = false;
                input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter numeric value: ");
            }
        } while (!good);
        return num;
    }
}

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

 // java class Titanic
public class Titanic {

    int MAXPASSENGERS = 10000;
    int actualPassengers = 0;
    //B. Use a 2D array to store the Titanic data. 
    String[][] data = new String[MAXPASSENGERS][6];

    /**
     * Constructor to read file and set 2D array to store the Titanic data
     */
    Titanic(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
            //line has tab delimeted data
            data[actualPassengers++] = fileReader.nextLine().split("\t");

        }
        fileReader.close();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Total number of passengers on the Titanic
     */
public int getTotalPassengers() {
        return actualPassengers;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Total number of passengers who perished on the Titanic
     */
    public int getTotalNumberofPerishedPassengers() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {

            int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
            //Survived (1=yes, 0=no)
            if (status == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Total number of Passengers who survived the sinking of the
     * Titanic
     */
    public int getTotalNumberofSurvivedPassengers() {
        return getTotalPassengers() - getTotalNumberofPerishedPassengers();
    }

    /**
     * Number of passengers who survived the sinking of the Titanic as a
     * function of the passenger class (e.g. 1,2,3)
     *
     * @param cls
     * @return
     */
    public int getTotalNumberofSurvivedPassengersByClass(int cls) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
            int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
            int clazz = Integer.parseInt(data[i][0]);
            //Survived (1=yes, 0=no)
            if (status == 1 && clazz == cls) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Number of passengers who survived the sinking of the Titanic as a
     * function of the passenger gender (e.g., male, female)
     *
     * @param cls
     * @return
     */
    public int getTotalNumberofSurvivedPassengersByGender(String gender) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
            int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
            //Survived (1=yes, 0=no)
            if (status == 1 && gender.equalsIgnoreCase(data[i][3])) {
                count++;
            } 
        }
        return count;
     }

    /**
     *
     * @param cls
     * @return A list of the names of passengers who paid greater than given
     * fair for their tickets
     */
    public String getNamesPaidFare(double fair) {
        String name = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
            if (data[i].length >= 6) {
            double pfair = Double.parseDouble(data[i][5]);
            if (pfair > fair) {
                name += "\n" + data[i][2];
            }
        }
    }
    return name;
}

/**
 * G. A list of the names of passengers who were less than 10 years old who
 * survived the sinking of the Titanic
 *
 * @param fair
 * @return
 */
public String getSurvivedNamesLessGivenAge(int age) {
    String name = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
        if (data[i].length >= 6 && data[i][4].length()>0) {
                int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
                double pAge = Double.parseDouble(data[i][4]);
            //Survived (1=yes, 0=no)
            if (status == 1 && pAge < age) {
                name += "\n" + data[i][2];
            }
        }
    }
    return name;
}

/**
 * H. A list of the names of passengers who were less than 10 years old who
 * perished on the Titanic
 *
 * @param fair
 * @return
 */
public String getPerishedNamesLessGivenAge(int age) {
   String name = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
        if (data[i].length >= 6 && data[i][4].length()>0) {
            int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
            double pAge = Double.parseDouble(data[i][4]);
            //Survived (1=yes, 0=no)
            if (status ==0 && pAge < age) {
                name += "\n" + data[i][2];
            }
        }
    }
    return name;
}

/**
 * The count of the number of passengers as a function of the first letter
 * of their last name. (e.g., A: 13, B:33 …)
 *
 * @param ch
 * @return
 */
public int getCountByFirstLetterOfFirstName(char ch) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
        char pChar = data[i][2].charAt(0);

        if (Character.toUpperCase(ch) == Character.toUpperCase(pChar)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

}

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show all of the code. These individual lines are meaningless without context.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException: 1` means that in `data[i][1]` one of the indices (either `i` or `1`) is greater than your array. It's likely that the exception refers to the second index. Then looking at the line where you fill the array. You use the `split()` method as a result for each line, so the second dimension of your array depends on the split result. If you read a string without a tab, `split()` returns a one element array. So you have to check, what the actual content of your array is. You should really learn some debugging techniques.

Comment: here is the debugging line that it failed on, but I've never used it before and I dont know what the error means. (i just recently started using netbeans. Before i was just using the cmd ln errors to figure out what I did wrong.
//line 83 of degugged code: `<java classpath="${classpath-translated}" classname="${classname}" dir="${work.dir}" jvm="${platform.java}" fork="true" failonerror="${java.failonerror}">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figured out the fix to the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds errors and got it to work. The only remaining issue with the above programs is that answering question 4 (survivors by class). Here's the code for that portion of the Titanic.java class that works:

```
    /**
     * Number of passengers who survived the sinking of the Titanic as a
     * function of the passenger class (e.g. 1,2,3)
     *
     * @param cls
     * @return
     */
    public int getTotalNumberofSurvivedPassengersByClass(int cls) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getTotalPassengers(); i++) {
            int status = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
            int clazz = Integer.parseInt(data[i][0]);
            //Survived (1 = yes, 0 = no)
            if (status == 1 && clazz == cls) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
```